# Finding Function's Extension and Its Unique Existence.

Tags: real-analysis, convergence-divergence, continuity, compactness, uniform-continuity

Let $$A= \left\{\frac j{2^n}\in [0,1] \mid n = 1,2,3,\ldots,\;j=0,1,2,\ldots,2^n\right\} $$ and let $$ f:A\rightarrow R    $$ satisfy the following condition:

There is a sequence $ \epsilon_n \gt 0 $ with $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \epsilon_n \lt \infty $ and $$\left|f\left(\frac{j-1}{2^n}\right)-f\left(\frac j{2^n}\right)\right| \lt \epsilon_n $$ for all $ n\gt0, j=1,2,\ldots,2^n $.

Prove that $f$ has a unique extension to a continuous function from $[0,1]$ to $R$.

---

I think it is maybe related to contraction mapping.

But, I could not apply that thery into this problem.

Is there anybody who can prove this?

p.s. The Formatting is helped by @Math1000. I appreciate that.

Comment: @Michael Hardy Do you have any idea to solve this?

Comment: Look at a ruler marked in inches.  Typically there's a vertical segment at integer numbers of inches, a shorter vertical segment at half-inches, a still shorter one at quarter-inches, and still shorter at eighth-inches.  That's what the graph of this function looks like.  Make it $0$ at all other points, i.e. those not in the set $A$. ${}\qquad{}$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An alternate answer that uses some of Alex Ravsky's method, but sticks to analysis methods, and in my opinion provides a more constructive demonstration:

For $x \in [0, 1]$, let $$x = \sum_{k = 1}^{\infty} \omega_{k}(x) 2^{-k},\; \omega_{k} \in \{0, 1 \}$$ i.e. suppose $(\omega_{k}(x))_{k \in \mathbb{N}}$ is the binary expansion of $x$, and define the extension of $f$ by $$f(x) = \lim_{n \to \infty} f\left(\sum_{k = 1}^{n} \omega_{k}(x) 2^{-k}\right).$$ We claim first that the sequence converges by showing it to be Cauchy for a given $x \in [0, 1]$, which we now fix. Let $\epsilon > 0$, and pick $N \in \mathbb{N}$ such that if $n \geq N$, then $\sum_{k = n}^{\infty} \epsilon_{n} < \epsilon$. Pick $m, n \geq N$. Then as Ravsky points out,
\begin{align*}
\left|f\left(\sum_{k = 1}^{n}\omega_{k}(x) 2^{-k}\right) - f\left(\sum_{k = 1}^{m}\omega_{k}(x) 2^{-k}\right)\right| & < \epsilon
\end{align*}

Boom. Cauchy, and thus convergent, so our extension is defined. Now, let $|y - x| < 2^{-(N + 2)}$. Having chosen $x$ and $y$ close enough, we have that $\omega_{k}(x) = \omega_{k}(y)$ for all $k \leq N$. Thus $$|f(x) - f(y)| \leq \sum_{k = N + 1}^{\infty} \epsilon_{k} < \epsilon,$$ completing the proof of continuity.

Comment: I found a gap in my answer, so I (temporarily) deleted it. The gap is that I have $|f(x_i)-f(x_i-2^{n_i})|<\epsilon_{n_i}$ provided the denominator of $x_i$ is not greater than $2^{n_i}$, which does not always hold.

Comment: I have two questions regarding your proof. I think BOLD CHARACTERS should be changed to as follows. How about your idea? 

1) define the extension of $f$ by $f(x) = \lim_{n \to \infty} f(\sum_{k = 1}^{n} \omega_{k}(x)2^{-k})$.

2) we have that $\omega_{k}(x) = \omega_{k}(y)$ for all $k \geq N$.

Thank you for your kind answer. Do you think it is a perfect proof?

Comment: Sorry that I am fail to make bold characters above.  Also, 'Perfect' was meant that do you think that my suggestion for modification of proof is right. Sorry for confusion.

Comment: Respectfully, I'm not sure I understand what your comment means.

Comment: Sorry for the confusion. I mean that, in second line of your proof, I want to ask that "define the extension of $f$ by $f(x) = \lim_{n \to \infty} f(\sum_{k = 1}^{n} \omega_{k}(x))$" changed to "$f$ by $f(x) = \lim_{n \to \infty} f(\sum_{k = 1}^{n} \omega_{k}(x)2^{-k})$"

Comment: Also, in second last line of proof, "$\omega_{k}(x) = \omega_{k}(y)$ for all $k \leq N$" to the "$\omega_{k}(x) = \omega_{k}(y)$ for all $k \geq N$"

Comment: Sorry. Think it's all fixed up.

Comment: I think that the inequality of k and N are still reverse.

Comment: No. $k \leq N$ means the two numbers' expansions will agree up to the $N$th digit. $k \geq N$ would mean they do something, and then agree for large $N$, which is not the goal.